# Fluid ignores gravity when hitting Effector, runs horizontal?

Tags: animation, physics, fluid-simulation, collision, mantaflow

I am new to this forum and just signed up to solve this problem that i have with Mantaflow simulations. See I watched a lot of tutorials about fluid simulations but still am relatively new to blender, just started using it mid 2021.

The fluid is supposed to act as a little drop of water running down to the edge of the effector, dripping off onto the ground in the end. However, as you see in the rendered animation (had to be under 2mb sorry), the simulation behaves like it is being dragged to left and right, instead of running straight down.

I tested a lot of settings and applied all transforms, this simulation is even scaled up tmes 16, because i thought it might be too small in size for the simulation to operate. Still no change in behaviour.

Maybe someone here knows what's my mistake and can help me and others facing the same thing...

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: pls provide blend file - you can either drop a link to e.g. google drive/dropbox or any cloud storage or....just delete your cache and upload your file

Comment: Stupid question on my behalf: how did you get a single drop when your fluid is set to _Inflow_ and the _Use Flow_ checkbox is not keyframed? Deleting your cache as @Chris suggested is always a good idea. And beware: changes in the _Flow_ object (like switching _Flow Behavior_ from _Inflow_ to _Geometry_ for example) will only have an effect after the _Domain_ resets in some way or another e.g. by changing settings, like setting the divisions from 64 to 66, then back to 64 again. For the sideway flow, see my answer.

Comment: maybe he has another inflow and keyframed that...

Comment: @Chris Well, if there's another it could be set to _Geometry_, no need for keyframes then... the wireframe view actually looks like there's a smaller sphere inside the larger sphere. Anyway, I was just curious, that's not the observed problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling *Fractional Obstacles* in the *Liquid* settings of the domain. This alone might already help, apart from that I would suggest to increase your *Resolution Divisions*. Other things you can try are increasing the *Sampling Substeps* on the effector.

[image: fractional obstacles]